# BufferedImage, int[] pixels and rendering. How do they work they work together?

Tags: java, rendering, game-engine, bufferedimage

There is something in the following code that I am unable to understand. After digging through google for a while, I decided it would be better to ask someone.
I am following a game programming tutorial on youtube, and I feel I understand (to some degree) everything I have written, except for some lines which concern the rendering part of the program.

```
package com.thomas.game;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.thomas.game.graphics.Screen;
import com.thomas.game.input.Keyboard;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {

private static final int WIDTH = 300;
private static final int HEIGHT = (WIDTH / 16) * 9;
private static final int SCALE = 3;
private static final String TITLE = "Game";

private JFrame frame;
private Thread thread;
private Screen screen;
private BufferedImage image;
private Keyboard key;

private int[] pixels;
private boolean running = false;

private int x = 0, y = 0;

public Game() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame = new JFrame();
    initializeFrame();
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

this is what I don't understand. I get the image raster, from which I get the databuffer. I typecast that databuffer into a (DatabufferInt), which allows me to retrieve an `int[]` through the `getData()` method. After this is done, pixel.length has a value of 48600, and every index contains the int value 0. Operating with this `int[]` makes the program render like it is supposed to. However, if I don't typecast and retrieve the `int[]` in the above manner, and instead say `pixels = new int[48600]`, i end up with a black screen.
I guess what I want to know is: what is the difference between these two `int[]`, or rather, what makes the first one work? How does it work?

```
    key = new Keyboard();
    addKeyListener(key);
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void run() {

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1E9/60;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    int ticks = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(running) {
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;

        while(delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            ticks++;
            delta--;
        }

        render();
        frames++;

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer >= 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            frame.setTitle(TITLE + " | ups: " + ticks + " fps: " + frames);
            ticks = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
    }
}

private void render() {

    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy(); // retrieves the bufferstrategy from the current component (the instance of Game that calls this method)
    if(bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    screen.clear();
    screen.render(x, y);
    getPixels();
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics(); // retrieves a graphics object from the next in line buffer in the bufferstrategy, this graphics object draws to that buffer
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null); // draws the bufferedimage to the available buffer
    g.dispose();
    bs.show(); // orders the next in line buffer (which the graphics object g is tied to) to show its contents on the canvas
}

private void tick() {
    key.update();
    if(key.up)
        y--;
    if(key.down)
        y++;
    if(key.left)
        x--;
    if(key.right)
        x++;
}

public void initializeFrame() {
    frame.setTitle(TITLE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public synchronized void start() {
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();
}

public void getPixels() {
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
}
}
```

It seems like the bufferedimage gets values from the pixels array. But I don't understand how these two communicate, or how they are connected. I haven't explicitly told the bufferedimage to get its pixels from the pixels array, so how does it know?
I will also attach the Screen class, which is responsible for updating the pixels array.

```
package com.thomas.game.graphics;

import java.util.Random;

public class Screen {

private int width, height;
public int[] pixels;
private final int MAP_SIZE = 64;
private final int MAP_SIZE_MASK = MAP_SIZE - 1;
private int[] tiles;
private int tileIndex;
private int xx, yy;

private Random r;

public Screen(int w, int h) {

    width = w;
    height = h;
    pixels = new int[width * height];
    tiles = new int[MAP_SIZE * MAP_SIZE];
    r = new Random(0xffffff);

    for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++) {
        tiles[i] = r.nextInt();
    }
    tiles[0] = 0;
}

public void clear() {
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        pixels[i] = 0;
}

public void render(int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        yy = y + yOffset;
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            xx = x + xOffset;
            tileIndex = (yy >> 4 & MAP_SIZE_MASK) * MAP_SIZE + (xx >> 4 & MAP_SIZE_MASK);
            pixels[y * width + x] = tiles[tileIndex];
        }
    }
}
}
```

I really hope someone can explain this to me, it would be greatly appreciated. The program is working like it is supposed to, but I don't feel comfortable continuing on the tutorial until I grasp this.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic types like short, int, long etc are not Objects.

However, int[] is an array. Arrays are objects in java. Java manipulates objects by reference, not value.

In this line you are not creating a new object. You are storing a reference to the object int[] in your variable `pixels`. Anything you change in `pixels`, gets changed inside of the int[] object in `image`:

```
pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

I've created an example, try running this code:

```
public class Data {
    private int[] values = {25,14};

    public int[] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Data d = new Data();
        System.out.println(d.getValues()[0]);

        int[] values = d.getValues();
        values[0] = 15;

        System.out.println(d.getValues()[0]);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
25
15
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have this code...

```
pixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

while it should be like this...

```
pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Change `image` to `img`.

Hope it works!